# Where'd my Avatar go?

Tags: support

I seem to have lost my Avatar :-(

I get a Security warning from Firefox by opening the following link (Avatar picture):
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3ef5b308d33027fab8440d223828fe4c?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG

Where is the issue? (Me, Stackoverflow, Gravatar, ...)

Comment: Looks okay to me

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Do you get an option to add an exception for that certificate?

Comment: @TylerH yes. But is it safe?

Comment: That certificate is not in the certchain I see. Your corporate IT is snooping into your secure connections ....

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk I don't see that certificate either; it should auto redirect to en.gravatar.com and be by "COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA" - I agree with rene, it sounds like there's a busybody in your corporate IT. I'd send an email and ask them to whitelist gravatar.com

Comment: https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/227987007